# Django-pyodbc mssql error for dumpdata

Tags: django, sql-server-2005, pyodbc, freetds, django-pyodbc

I am trying to perform a `sudo ./manage.py dumpdata` on a mssql db from my django project, but keep getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 338, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/dumpdata.py", line 158, in handle
    stream=self.stdout)
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/serializers/__init__.py", line 128, in serialize
    s.serialize(queryset, **options)
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/serializers/base.py", line 52, in serialize
    for obj in queryset:
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/dumpdata.py", line 150, in get_objects
    for obj in queryset.iterator():
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 265, in iterator
    for row in compiler.results_iter():
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 701, in results_iter
    for rows in self.execute_sql(MULTI):
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 785, in execute_sql
    cursor = self.connection.cursor()
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 165, in cursor
    cursor = self.make_debug_cursor(self._cursor())
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sql_server/pyodbc/base.py", line 230, in _cursor
    autocommit=autocommit)
pyodbc.Error: ('IM002', '[IM002] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

I have done the configuration mentioned in https://code.google.com/p/django-pyodbc/wiki/FreeTDS, and I get all the test working (FreeTDS & ODBC).

Here is my current `settings.py` database config:

```
DATABASES = {
    ...
    'vcoe':
        {
            'ENGINE' : 'sql_server.pyodbc',
            'NAME' : 'VOIP',
            'USER' : '******',
            'PASSWORD' : '******',
            'OPTIONS' : {
                'driver': 'FreeTDS',
                'dsn': 'VCOE',
            }
        }
}

DATABASE_ENGINE = 'sql_server.pyodbc'
DATABASE_NAME = 'VOIP'
DATABASE_USER = '******'
DATABASE_PASSWORD = '******'
DATABASE_OPTIONS = {
    'driver': 'FreeTDS',
    'dsn': 'VCOE', # ODBC DSN name defined in your odbc.ini
}
```

When I try and run `./manage.py test` I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 50, in run_from_argv
    super(Command, self).run_from_argv(argv)
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 71, in execute
    super(Command, self).execute(*args, **options)
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 338, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 88, in handle
    failures = test_runner.run_tests(test_labels)
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 147, in run_tests
    old_config = self.setup_databases()
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 109, in setup_databases
    return setup_databases(self.verbosity, self.interactive, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 299, in setup_databases
    serialize=connection.settings_dict.get("TEST", {}).get("SERIALIZE", True),
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/creation.py", line 362, in create_test_db
    self._create_test_db(verbosity, autoclobber)
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/creation.py", line 455, in _create_test_db
    with self._nodb_connection.cursor() as cursor:
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 167, in cursor
    cursor = utils.CursorWrapper(self._cursor(), self)
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sql_server/pyodbc/base.py", line 181, in _cursor
    raise ImproperlyConfigured('You need to specify NAME in your Django settings file.')
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: You need to specify NAME in your Django settings file.
```

I have tried to remove the `DATABASES = {...}` section and only leave the `DATABASE_XXX` but get:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more details.
```

Im currently using on client:

- Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
- Python 2.7.6
- Django 1.7.8
- pyodbc==3.0.10
- django-pyodbc==0.2.8

Server I'm reaching is:

- Microsoft Server 2003 running: MSSQL 2005

Here is `/etc/odbcinst.ini`:

```
[FreeTDS]
    Description = TDS driver (Sybase/MS SQL)
    Driver = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so
    Setup = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsS.so
    CPTimeout =
    CPReuse =
```

Double checked path, all files are present

Here is my `/etc/odbc.ini`:

```
[ODBC Data Sources]
ODBCNAME = Microsoft SQL Server

[VCOE]
Driver = FreeTDS
Description = VOIP Legacy Database
Trace = No
Servername = VOIP
Database = VOIP

[Default]
Driver = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so
```

here is my `/etc/freetds/freetds.conf`:

```
[VOIP]
host = 142.117.139.***
port = 1433
tds version = 8.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using a very, very old version of django-pyodbc that is no longer maintained. That was last updated in 2011. I've had problems with older versions and using `dumpdata` and `dbshell`. I would recommend using this version, actively maintained, which has been working wonderfully for me in several Django projects:

https://github.com/michiya/django-pyodbc-azure

Note, to install it, you'll have to do this, since you're not using Django 1.8:

```
pip install django-pyodbc-azure<1.8
```

Off-topic: I'd recommend using Django 1.8.x if you're just starting on a project. While Django 1.7.x is still supported, Django 1.8.x is a long-term release, meaning it will be supported for at least three years. Good luck!